# jQuery - Selecting Bootstrap Nav Tabs with Links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've setup the Bootstrap/jQuery nav-tabs. The tabs themselves work as expected, however I need to have buttons within the tab content that also activate the next tab.

The buttons I've added force the tab-content active, however the tab `li` are not being updated.

I have setup a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3v1L5rw/) to display the problem.

```html
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#next-move-home" data-toggle="tab">HOME</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#next-move-1-0" data-toggle="tab">1.0</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#next-move-2-0" data-toggle="tab">2.0</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#next-move-3-0" data-toggle="tab">3.0</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#next-move-4-0" data-toggle="tab">4.0</a></li>
      
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="next-move-home">
            <h2>Home</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="#next-move-1-0" data-toggle="tab">1.0</a>
  </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="next-move-1-0">
            <h2>1.0</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="#next-move-2-0" data-toggle="tab">2.0</a>
  </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="next-move-2-0">
            <h2>2.0</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="#next-move-3-0" data-toggle="tab">3.0</a>
  </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="next-move-3-0">
            <h2>3.0</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
      <a class="btn btn-default" href="#next-move-4-0" data-toggle="tab">4.0</a>
  </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="next-move-4-0">
            <h2>4.0</h2>
            <p>Content</p>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tab-content a").click(function () {
        if (this.href.indexOf("next-move") >= 0) {
            $(".nav-tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
            $(".nav-tabs li a[href=" + this.hash + "]").parent().addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#next-move-home" data-toggle="tab">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#next-move-1-0" data-toggle="tab">1.0</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#next-move-2-0" data-toggle="tab">2.0</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#next-move-3-0" data-toggle="tab">3.0</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#next-move-4-0" data-toggle="tab">4.0</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="next-move-home">
         <h2>Home</h2>

        <p>Content</p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="#next-move-1-0" data-toggle="tab">1.0</a>

    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="next-move-1-0">
         <h2>1.0</h2>

        <p>Content</p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="#next-move-2-0" data-toggle="tab">2.0</a>

    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="next-move-2-0">
         <h2>2.0</h2>

        <p>Content</p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="#next-move-3-0" data-toggle="tab">3.0</a>

    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="next-move-3-0">
         <h2>3.0</h2>

        <p>Content</p> <a class="btn btn-default" href="#next-move-4-0" data-toggle="tab">4.0</a>

    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="next-move-4-0">
         <h2>4.0</h2>

        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```